# Bash scrip passing argument in quotes

Tags: bash, date, arguments, escape-characters

i have command like this

```
date -d @$(date -d 'Sat, 08 Aug 2020 00:00:00' "+%s")  +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

which output this

```
2020-08-08
```

So i want to use thins in bash scrip, i created this (this is just part of realy big script)

```
Date1=$1
date -d @$(date -d $Date1 "+%s")  +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

But when i try to run like this

```
./test.sh "Sat, 08 Aug 2020 00:00:00"
```

I get

```
date: extra operand ‘Aug’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
date: invalid date ‘@’
```

So its look like that "" desapear when passing argument

Comment: You need to quote the `$Date1`. Otherwise, it will be expanded as `date -d Sat, 08 Aug 2020 00:00:00 "+%s"`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `$Date1` inside the quotes and it should work:

```
date -d @$(date -d "$Date1" "+%s")  +'%Y-%m-%d'
```

See also [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)